# Probability distribution binomial

Tags: probability

An assembly system is composed of n independent and identical parts. During any given “run” of the system, all parts have a probability of p of working. Suppose the random variable Y represents the number of working parts in any given “run”. You are told that P(Y=3) = 2P(Y=2) and V[Y] = p. What is the probability distribution of Y?

I know thus is a binomial wherein the mean is np and the variance is np(1-p) how would you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the trivial solution $p=0$, in which case $n$ is cannot be determined. Assume now that $p\ne 0$.

We have $\Pr(Y=3)=\binom{n}{3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}$ and $\Pr(Y=2)=\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$.

We were told that 
$$\binom{n}{3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}=2\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}.$$
Thus 
$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}=2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}.$$
A bit of algebra simplifies this to
$$(n-2)p=6(1-p).\tag{1}$$
The information about the variance tells us that $n(1-p)=1$.

Solve for $p$, by replacing $n$ in (1) by $\frac{1}{1-p}$. We get $p=\frac{3}{4}$ and then $n=4$.

Comment: Thanks Andre I did it this way as well, but looks like I missed alot of steps. Thank you again!